# masking a string with #

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, loops

Hi can someone please look over my code and tell me what i have to fix. The function of this code is that it takes any given string in the argument and hides the characters of the string with a #. All the characters are hidden except the last 4. I dont know why I am not getting the desired output. Please feel free to run the code and see. I would prefer the solutions to be corrections or improvements to my code and not new pieces of code. Thank you!

```js
const maskify = (info) => {
  let fourSaved = info.slice((info.substr(-4))) // put a negative number within the parameters so it starts from backwards. This variable will save the last 4 characters of the string.
  const infoArr = info.split(", ") //turned string into an array for easier manipulation

  for(let i = 0; i < infoArr.length; i++){
    infoArr[i] = "#" //so each and every element in the array is changed into a #
    console.log(infoArr.join(''));
  }
  let arrStr = infoArr.join(''); //Changing array back to string
  let masked = arrStr.replace(arrStr.substr(-4), fourSaved); // putting the last 4 characters of the string back into it.
  return masked 
}
console.log(maskify("hello world")) //desired output should be: ##### #orld
```

Comment: You would be much better off using a `for()` loop that just iterates over the string from `0` to `string.length - 4` and replacing each character that way. This code is needlessly complex.

Comment: This is a great opportunity to familiarize yourself with the use of a debugger.  For example, if you are running this code on a web page then you can use your browser's built-in script debugger (if it doesn't have one, Chrome does) to place a breakpoint at the first line within the function and re-invoke (possibly by reloading the page) to begin debugging.  Once debugging, you can step through the code line by line as it executes and observe the exact runtime results of each specific operation.  When you do that, which operation is the first to produce an unexpected result?

Comment: Seconding @David 's comment, and noting that you can also simply add a single line statement `debugger;` to cause the debugger to break on that line as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```js
  const maskify = (info) => {
  return info.slice(0, -4).replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g, '#').concat(info.slice(-4, info.len));
}
console.log(maskify("hello world")) //desired output should be: ##### #orld
```

**Explanation:**

First, I slice the string until the last four letters.
Then, replace all the characters in the returned string with pound character.
This is done by using **Javascript Regular Expression**, this specific one replaces all of the letters in the string (between a-z and A-Z).

After that, concat that string with the last 4 characters of the original string.
Finally, the result is returned.

*For more info on Regex:*

[MDN regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

[Example](https://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/all-letters-field.php)


**Your Code, Changed:**

If you purposefully want to use the loop way, here is your code changed so it returns the correct result:

```js
  const maskify = (info) => {
  let fourSaved = info.slice(-4) // put a negative number within the parameters so it starts from backwards. This variable will save the last 4 characters of the string.
  const infoArr = info.split(", ") //turned string into an array for easier manipulation
  for(let i = 0; i < infoArr.length; i++){
      infoArr[i] =infoArr[i].replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g, '#') //so each and every element in the array is changed into a #
  }
  let arrStr = infoArr.join(''); //Changing array back to string
  let masked = arrStr.slice(0, -4) + fourSaved;
  return masked 
}
console.log(maskify("hello world")) //desired output should be: ##### #orld
```

Comment: Hi @BatshevaRich  It worked! Thanks! Can you explain this portion of the code: /[a-zA-Z]/g? And if there is a link on MDN explaining this concept further I'd appreciate it!

Comment: @KazimShabbir edited the answer, hope that explained things...

Comment: Thank you it makes perfect sense! @BatshevaRich

Comment: @KazimShabbir great! please upvote the answer if it was helpful.